# How to input integer value to an array, based preceeding row + column values?

Tags: ruby, arrays

For this following project, I am supposed to take input in the following format : R1C5+2 , which reads it as "in the table, Row 1 Column 5 ,add 2. Or in this format : R1C2C3-5 , which reads : "in the table, Row 1 Column 2-3, subtract 5. This is assuming that all numbers in the table are initially all 0.

Where I left Off:

I am having trouble finding a way to detect for a "+" or "-" to either add/subtract values in the table. Also, in providing a range to allow multiple additions when provided two C's or R's. For example: R1R5C2C3+2 (Row Range 1 - 5, Column Range 2 - 3, add 2).

Here is the following code:

```
puts 'Please input: '
x = gets.chomp

col = []
row = []

x.chars.each_slice(2) { |u|  u[0] == "R" ? row << u[1] : col << u[1] }

p col
p row

puts "Largest # in Row array: #{row.max}"
puts "Largest # in Columns array: #{col.max}" #must be in "" to return value

big_row = row.max.to_i
big_col = col.max.to_i


table = Array.new (big_row) { Array.new(big_col) }
```

I thank you all for the help!

Comment: This should probably be tagged as homework

Comment: You'll probably want to loop through the chars until you match a `-` or a `+`

Comment: Oh no i know that, but it doesnt seem to work with me.

Comment: @user3315041 Check my solution below and accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Your homework, sir.

```
puts 'Please input: '
x = gets.chomp

col = []
row = []
sign = ''
val = ''

x.chars.each_slice(2) do |u|
  case u[0]
  when 'R' then
    row << u[1]
  when 'C' then
    col << u[1]
  when '+', '-'
    sign, val = u[0], u[1]
  else
    puts 'Invalid input.'
    exit
  end
end

big_row = row.max.to_i
big_col = col.max.to_i
table = Array.new (big_row) { Array.new(big_col) }

# Initialize table to all zeros
table.map! do |row|
  row.map! { |col| 0 }
end

rows_range = row.length == 1 ? row[0]..row[0] : row[0]..row[1]
cols_range = col.length == 1 ? col[0]..col[0] : col[0]..col[1]

table.each_with_index do |row, ri|
  if rows_range.include? (ri + 1).to_s
    row.each_with_index do |col, ci|
      if cols_range.include? (ci + 1).to_s
        table[ri][ci] = (sign + val).to_i
      end
    end
  end
end

# Padding for fields in table.
padding = 4

# Table
table.each do |row|
  row.each do |col|
    print "#{col.to_s.rjust(padding)}"
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

Comment: Will it work for R1C5+20 ?

Comment: @Nik, it doesn't, but does it need to?

Comment: No idea. Homeworks can have limited scope, while in the real life, i guess, any number can be expected

Comment: thank you all for the help, but is this algorithm registering values to the array, or only acknowledging the +/- character?

Comment: @user3315041 It's putting the +/- into the `sign` variable and how much to add/subtract into `val`.

Comment: @user3315041 Click the checkmark next to my answer and we'll call it even :)

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally posted this twice. Here is the answer I gave on the other copy:

The method you are looking for is the `=~` operator. If you use it on a string and give it a regexp pattern it will return the location of that pattern in the string. Thus:

```
x = 'R1C2C3-5'

x =~ /R/
```

returns: `0` since that is the position of 'R' in the string (counted just like an array 0,1,2...).

If you are unfamiliar with regexp and the `=~` operator, I suggest you check out the Ruby doc on it, it is very valuable. Basically the pattern between the forward slashes get matched. You are looking to match `+` or `-`, but they have special meaning in regexp, so you have to escape them with a backslash.

```
x =~ /\+/
x =~ /\-/
```

but you can combine those into one pattern matcher with an OR symbol (pipe) `|`

```
x =~ /\+|\-/
```

So now you have a method to get the operator:

```
def operator(my_string)
  r = my_string.slice(my_string =~ /\+|\-/)
end
```

I would also use the operator to split your string into the column/row part and the numeric part:

```
op = operator(x)    # which returns op = '-'
arr = x.split(my_string(x))  # which returns an array of two strings ['R1C2C3', '5']
```

I leave further string manipulation up to you. I would read through this page on the String class: [Ruby String Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html) and this on arrays: [Ruby Array Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html) as Ruby contains so many methods to make things like this easier. One thing I've learned to do with Ruby is think "I want to do this, I wonder if there is already a built in method to do this?" and I go check the docs. Even more so with Rails!

Comment: Since this is homework I just gave you the lead on `=~`. You should be able to use the string and array methods I linked to finish your work. I'll also give a hint on how to use the string '-' or '+' as a plus or minus operator in a math equation, look up the `send()` ruby method.