# Iteration in a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, input

I am having trouble iterating through a 2d array. I would like to simply set for each index in this array a starting value of 0. I can create the table, but now I want to set initial values.

The input format is as follows:
  R5C4+2. (This reads as , a table with 5 Rows and 4 columns, at which all values in the table are of value of 2).

Initial table:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

After input:

```
2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2
```

Probem is I can't even get to setting all table indexes with initial value of 0, let alone updating each value.

My code so far:

```
row = []
sign = ''
val = ''

x.chars.each_slice(2) do |u|
  case u[0]
    when 'R' then
      row << u[1]
    when 'C' then
      col << u[1]
    when '+', '-'
      sign, val = u[0], u[1]
    else
      puts 'Invalid input.'
    exit
  end
end

p col
p row
puts sign, val

big_row = row.max.to_i
big_col = col.max.to_i

table = Array.new (big_row) { Array.new(big_col) }

require 'narray'
table = NArray[big_row][big_col]

table.each do |(x,y)|
  x = 0
  y = 0
  puts x,y
end
```

Comment: Check your other posts.  I solved this problem for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21818644/1550111 @user3315041

Answer (score 0):

```
table = Array.new (row) { Array.new(col,2) }
```

where 2 is your initial value.